# Copying a single file to multiple directories using cp

Tags: bash, shell, cp

This question is a sequel of sorts to my earlier question, [Creating numerous directories using `mkdir`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48750/creating-numerous-directories-using-mkdir).

I am using the `bash` shell.  I have created fifty directories, each starting with the prefix "s", using the command:

```
mkdir $(printf "s%02i " $(seq 1 50))
```

which pads to the second digit with zeros.  That is, the directories that I obtain are of the form `s01`, `s02`, ..., `s49`, `s50`.

Now I would like to use `cp` to copy a single file (for example, `test.txt`) to each of the fifty directories.  Is it possible to do this in a way analogous to that above?  For example, would the following work? I am relatively new to Unix/Linux, so I don't really want to try this until someone please gives me an indication that it is safe.

cp test.txt $(printf "s%02i.txt " $(seq 1 50))

Looking at the `man` page for `cp`, it does not look like `cp` supports multiple destinations like this, however:

```
NAME
       cp - copy files and directories

SYNOPSIS
       cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
       cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
       cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...

DESCRIPTION
       Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.

       Mandatory  arguments  to  long  options are mandatory for short options
       too.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wanted to use the output from your command to copy the file to each directory using `cp`, you could always pipe it to `xargs`:

```
printf "s%02i " $(seq 1 50) | xargs -n 1 cp test.txt
```

There shouldn't be any concerns about the safety of parsing the output since you know its format and content before hand--the risk of encountering meta characters and space in file names isn't really an issue here.

Alternatively, assuming the directories already exist, you could try something like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 's[0-9][0-9]' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} cp test.txt {}
```

or with no pipe:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 's[0-9][0-9]' -exec cp test.txt {} \;
```

The last two commands will find any files in the current directory and `cp` `test.txt` to them. The `-maxdepth 1` option will avoid any sub directories receiving the file as well. Be warned that `'s[0-9][0-9]'` is matching against `s` followed by any two digits, which means if for some reason you have `s99` in the `cwd`, it will also receive a copy of `test.txt`.

Answer (score 9):

You can also let the shell do the iterations with a `for` loop.  This is the most basic way that doesn't rely on external tools like `parallel` or `xargs`, and I find it easiest to understand:

```
for name in $(printf "s%02i " $(seq 1 50)); do
    mkdir $name
    cp test.txt $name
done
```

There are a million other ways to write this, e.g.:

```
for name in $(seq -w 1 50); do
    mkdir s$name
    cp test.txt s$name
done
```

If you want to verify what would be executed before doing it, you can do something like prepending the commands with `echo`, which will print the line rather than executing it:

```
for name in $(seq -w 1 50); do
    echo mkdir s$name
    echo cp test.txt s$name
done
```

outputs:

```
mkdir s01
cp test.txt s01
mkdir s02
cp test.txt s02
mkdir s03
cp test.txt s03
# etc.
```

Answer (score 4):

According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195655/how-to-copy-a-file-to-multiple-directories-using-the-gnu-cp-command it is not possible to copy one file to multiple destinations.  Check the link, as it shows another way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use GNU [parallel](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel/). Assuming your are in the directory containing text.txt and your 50 dirs are located in `/my/50dirs/path` (like `/my/50dirs/path/s01`, `/my/50dirs/path/s02` etc) you would run:

```
seq -w 01 50 | parallel -j1 cp text.txt /my/50dirs/path/s{}
```

Comment: Better make that `parallel -j1`, otherwise there will be one job per core, and on a multicore machine the jobs will compete for IO.

Comment: ... unless the destinations are on different drives etc